# How to customize unordered list bullet using inline CSS only (for emails)?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way of replacing the standard unordered list (`<ul><li>...</li></ul>`) bullets and spacing with unique Unicode character-based bullets and spacing, using only inline CSS (for use in HTML emails).

Here is the code I would normally use in my "external" CSS file for a standard HTML web page:

```css
ul.med_sqr_bul_ul
    {
        list-style:none !important;

        padding:0px !important;
    }

ul.med_sqr_bul_ul li:before
    {
        content:'\25AA';

        margin:0 0.28em;

        font-size:150% !important;
        vertical-align:-10%;
    }
```

The problem is that HTML emails are restricted to inline CSS, which does not support pseudo-elements like `:before`.

How can I accomplish the same effect, using inline CSS only?

Comment: can you just use a `<span>` instead of the puesdo element?

Comment: @zgood doing it in CSS is better for accessibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify unicode character points as a value for the [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) property.

For example, [Unicode Character 'THUMBS UP SIGN' (U+1F44D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm) can be used like so:

```html
<p>My custom list</p>

<!-- change the unicode character and how far the list is indented here -->
<ul style="list-style-type: '\1F44D'; margin-left: 0.5em">
  <!-- padding-left is the spacing between the text and the list character -->
  <!-- padding-bottom is the vertical spacing between each list item -->
  <li style="padding-left: 0.25em; padding-bottom: 0.25em">one</li>
  <li style="padding-left: 0.25em; padding-bottom: 0.25em">two</li>
  <li style="padding-left: 0.25em; padding-bottom: 0.25em">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer! Now just as a side-note how would I customize the spacing to the left and right (esp. between the bullet and `<li>...</li>` content) of the bullet?

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. Use padding

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. note: since you're using ['BLACK SMALL SQUARE' (U+25AA)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/025aa/index.htm), another option is to just use `list-style-type: square`.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I want the bullet to be slightly larger than the typical `list-style-type: square`. Is there a way the change the font size of the bullet alone without affecting the font-size of the actual `<li>...</li>` content?

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. for that, i think you'll have to set the font-size of the list, then wrap each `li`'s content in a `span` and set a smaller `font-size` for the `span`s.